# Not able to get Custom Domain for CD server

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms

We are using Sitecore 9 Form with Custom Submit action for Creating new user (Registration Form). Here is the code for creating new user

```
public bool CreateUser(UserDetails userDetails)
{
    //string userName = string.Concat(userDetails.FirstName, userDetails.LastName);
    string userName = userDetails.Email;
    string domainName = Sitecore.Context.Domain != null ? Sitecore.Context.Domain.Name : string.Empty;
    userName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domainName, userName);
    if (!Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(userName))
    {
        Membership.CreateUser(userName, userDetails.Password, userDetails.Email);

        // Edit the profile information
        Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(userName, true);
        Sitecore.Security.UserProfile userProfile = user.Profile;
        userProfile.FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", userDetails.FirstName, userDetails.LastName);
        //userProfile.Comment = userDetails.Comment;
        //var profileItemId = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("MyProfileItemId") != null ? Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("MyProfileItemId").ToString() : string.Empty;
        CustomConfigurations customConfiguration = new CustomConfigurations();
        var profileItemId = customConfiguration.GetSetting("MyProfileItemId");
        // Assigning the user profile template
        userProfile.SetPropertyValue("ProfileItemId", profileItemId);

        // Have modified the user template to also contain telephone number and job title.
        userProfile.SetCustomProperty("FirstName", userDetails.FirstName != null ? userDetails.FirstName : string.Empty);
        userProfile.SetCustomProperty("LastName", userDetails.LastName != null ? userDetails.LastName : string.Empty);
        userProfile.SetCustomProperty("TelephoneNumber", userDetails.TelephoneNumber != null ? userDetails.TelephoneNumber : string.Empty);
        userProfile.SetCustomProperty("Extension", userDetails.Extension != null ? userDetails.Extension : string.Empty);
        userProfile.SetCustomProperty("AlternatePhoneNumber", userDetails.AlternatePhoneNumber != null ? userDetails.AlternatePhoneNumber : string.Empty);
        userProfile.SetCustomProperty("AlternatePhoneNumberExtension", userDetails.AlternatePhoneNumberExtension != null ? userDetails.AlternatePhoneNumberExtension : string.Empty);
        if (userDetails.IsHcp)
        {
            userProfile.SetCustomProperty("IsHcp", "1");
            userProfile.SetCustomProperty("DateOfHCPUpdate", DateUtil.ToIsoDate(DateTime.Now));
        }
        userProfile.SetCustomProperty("PasswordResetKey", string.Empty);
        if (userDetails.IsSubscribedForUpdates
            {userProfile.SetCustomProperty("IsSubscribedForUpdates", "1");
        }
        if (userDetails.IsAgreedForTermsAndConditions)
        {
            userProfile.SetCustomProperty("IsAgreedForTermsAndConditions", "1");
        }
        userProfile.Save();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The method is returning true but the user is getting created with username default\email always instead of my_domain/email and the custom domain is set in the below path

**Path**: /sitecore/content/{mysite}/Settings/Site Grouping/mysitedef1

**Field**: Domain is set to my_domain

The requirement is working fine in CM Server (my_domain/email)

Comment: Is there a reason you are creating a user instead of, or in addition to, a xConnect Contact for xDB? Many of the fields listed are facets on a contact. http://sitecorehacker.com/2018/01/28/sitecore-users-vs-sitecore-contacts-one-is-not-like-the-other/

Comment: 2nd question: what domain is configured on the site definition on the CD?

Comment: @PeteNavarra, We are Creating a new user with custom User Profile.The domain configured is same as CM (my_domain)